# regarding error in gui based password manager using tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, pymysql

There is a single problem with the code.
In the "asking the user for their password", I am using a variable

```
entry
```

for taking the user's password and then i have a "submit" button. I assigned a command "logpass" to the button so that the function takes the password (using entry.get()) and then deleted the content of existing window and makes a new label (i.e. asking the user to "CHOOSE") and 2 radio buttons (log the password, or just copy the password) but its showing that in "entry.get()", the entry variable is undefined, even though it had just been defined before executing the function.

`

```
import random
from tkinter import Checkbutton, Label,LabelFrame,Button, PhotoImage, Radiobutton, Tk,Entry,IntVar,CENTER
import pyperclip
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host="sql12.freemysqlhosting.net",user="sql12540395",password="Th5YTnw4FX",port=3306,database="sql12540395")
c = conn.cursor()
#c.execute("create table passlog(sno int primary key not null auto_increment, softname varchar(50),password varchar(256))")
#c.execute("show tables")
def intodb():
    c.execute("insert into passlog(softname,password) values(%s,%s)",(softname,passw))
    conn.commit()
    print ([i for i in c.fetchall()])

window = Tk()
window.title("PASSWORD MANAGER")
p1 = PhotoImage(file="lock.png")
window.iconphoto(False,p1)
passw=""
#this func is defined when the user selects no for generating random pass
def logpass():
    def logOrCopy1():
        if rvar.get()==1:
            print ("Enter into database")
            intodb()
        elif rvar.get()==2:
            pyperclip.copy(passw)
            print ("Successfully Copied!")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    passw=entry.get()
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
                    widget.destroy()
    labelframe = LabelFrame(
                    window,
                    relief = "raised",
                    height = 400,
                    borderwidth=10,
                    width = 400
                    )
    labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

    label=Label(labelframe,text="Choose",font=("Lucida Sans",15))
    label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    rvar = IntVar()
    r1 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text= "Log the password", variable=rvar,command=logOrCopy1,font = ("Lucida Sans",10), value =1)
    r2 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text="Copy the password",variable=rvar,command=logOrCopy1,value=2,font =("Lucida Sans",10))
    r1.pack(anchor=CENTER,padx=10,pady=10)
    r2.pack(anchor=CENTER,pady=10,padx=10)
    btn = Button(labelframe,text="Go Back To Main Menu",command=mainmenu,font=("Lucida Sans",7))
    btn.pack(padx=5,pady=5)


def create():
    def softnamebtn():
        def yesno():
            def genpass():
                def logOrCopy():
                    def logOrCopy1():
                        if rvar.get()==1:
                            intodb()
                        elif rvar.get()==2:
                            pyperclip.copy(passw)
                            print ("Successfully Copied!")
                        else:
                            print("Invalid")

                    if rvar.get()==1:
                       intodb()
                    elif rvar.get()==2:
                        pyperclip.copy(passw)
                        print ("Successfully Copied!")
                    else:
                        print("Invalid")
                genpasslen = int(entry.get())
                for widget in window.winfo_children():
                    widget.destroy()
                global passw
                passw=""
                for i in range(genpasslen):
                    passw+=chr(random.randint(33,126))
                print (passw)
                labelframe = LabelFrame(
                    window,
                    relief = "raised",
                    height = 400,
                    borderwidth=10,
                    width = 400
                    )
                labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

                label = Label(labelframe,text="Choose",font=("Lucida Sans",15))
                label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

                rvar = IntVar()
                r1 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text= "Log the password", variable=rvar,command=logOrCopy,font = ("Lucida Sans",10), value =1)
                r2 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text="Copy the password",variable=rvar,command=logOrCopy,value=2,font =("Lucida Sans",10))
                r1.pack(anchor=CENTER,padx=10,pady=10)
                r2.pack(anchor=CENTER,pady=10,padx=10)
                btn = Button(labelframe,text="Go Back To Main Menu",command=mainmenu,font=("Lucida Sans",7))
                btn.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

            if var.get()==1:
                print ("Random Pass")
                for widget in window.winfo_children():
                    widget.destroy()


                labelframe = LabelFrame(
                    window,
                    relief = "raised",
                    height = 400,
                    borderwidth=10,
                    width = 400
                    )
                labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

                label = Label(labelframe,text="Enter the length for the randomly generated password : ",font=("Lucida Sans",15))
                label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
                entry = Entry(labelframe,font = ("Lucida Sans",10))
                entry.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
                btn = Button(labelframe,text="Submit",font = ("Lucida Sans",10), command=genpass)
                btn.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

            elif var.get()==2:
                for widget in window.winfo_children():
                    widget.destroy()
                labelframe = LabelFrame(
                    window,
                    relief = "raised",
                    height = 400,
                    borderwidth=10,
                    width = 400
                    )
                labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
                label = Label(labelframe,text="Enter Your Password",font=("Lucida Sans",15))
                label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
                entry = Entry(labelframe, font=("Lucida Sans",10))
                entry.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
                btn = Button(labelframe,text = "Submit", font=("Lucida Sans",9),command=logpass)
                btn.pack(padx=5,pady=5)


            else:
                print ("Invalid Operation")
        global softname
        softname = entry.get()
        #print (softname)
        #window.destroy()
        for widget in window.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        labelframe = LabelFrame(
        window,
        relief = "raised",
        height = 400,
        borderwidth=10,
        width = 400
        )
        labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

        label = Label(labelframe,font = ("Lucida Sans",15),text="Do you want a randomly generated password? ")
        label.pack(padx=10,pady=10,anchor=CENTER)

        var = IntVar()
        r1 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text= "Yes", variable=var,font = ("Lucida Sans",10), value =1,command=yesno)
        r2 = Radiobutton(labelframe,text="No",variable=var, value=2,command=yesno,font =("Lucida Sans",10))
        r1.pack(anchor=CENTER,padx=5,pady=5)
        r2.pack(anchor=CENTER,pady=5,padx=5)

    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    labelframe = LabelFrame(
        window,
        relief = "raised",
        height = 400,
        borderwidth=10,
        width = 400
        )
    labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

    label = Label(
            labelframe,
            text = "Enter the name of the software: ",
            font = ("Lucida Sans",15)
            )
    label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    entry = Entry(
            labelframe,
            )
    entry.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    btn = Button(
            labelframe,
            text = "Submit",
            font = ("Lucida Sans",10),
            command = softnamebtn
            )
    btn.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

def mainmenu():
    for widget in window.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    labelframe = LabelFrame(
        window,
        relief = "raised",
        height = 400,
        borderwidth=10,
        width = 400
        )
    labelframe.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

    label = Label(
        labelframe,
        text = "PASSWORD MANAGER",
        font = ("Lucida Sans",15)
        )
    label.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
    btn = Button(
        labelframe,
        text = "Create",
        font = ("Lucida Sans",10),
        command = create
        )

    btn.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

mainmenu()

window.mainloop()
```

`

and also if possible, please arrange my code in a more  "readable" way
Thank You!

Comment: You just posted your password

Comment: `entry` is local to the `genpass` function.  To refer it in other functions, you need to make it a global.  Your code is a nightmare.  I can't imagine what you're trying to do with 6 levels of nested functions, but it is a maintenance nightmare.  Please learn about classes.

Comment: *'please arrange my code in a more "readable" way'* Here at Stack Overflow we answer questions. We don't do your work.